# Using Set instead of List cause "Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion" exception

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I was getting the error *"Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion"* when trying to access the endpoint http://localhost:8080/categoryOfPermissions. I've researched and found various solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693110/could-not-write-json-infinite-recursion-stackoverflowerror-nested-exception) (`@JsonManagedReference / @JsonBackReference`, `@JsonIgnore`, `@JsonIdentityInfo`), but none of them seemed to work. Finally, I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57055767/4077150) stating that it was necessary to change from Set to List, in order for the `@JsonIdentityInfo` solution to work. I tested it an it really starts to work after changing from Set to List.

I thought that it was strange, but I found out something even stranger: after changing from Set to List, I removed the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotations and everything continued to work. In other words, all that I really needed to do was changing from Set to List to get rid of the exception. Nothing else. No need of any of the solutions :`@JsonManagedReference / @JsonBackReference`, `@JsonIgnore`, `@JsonIdentityInfo`.

Below is the code that was producing the exception. All I had to do was changing `private Set<Permission> permission` to `private List<Permission> permission`.

I would like to know why, especially because I would prefer to use Set, in order to avoid Hibernate to use the "Bags" paradigm (which may cause [some undesirable behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17950928/4077150)).

**Permission.java :**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Permission{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
            
    @NotNull    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_of_permission_id")
    private CategoryOfPermission categoryOfPermission;    
}
```

**CategoryOfPermission.java :**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class CategoryOfPermission{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
            
    @NotNull    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "categoryOfPermission", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Permission> permission;
}
```

**CategoryOfPermissionRepo.java :**

```
public interface CategoryOfPermissionRepo extends CrudRepository<CategoryOfPermission, Integer>{
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is because `Set` in `Java` uses `equals` contract to determine whether two objects are the same or not, and the way `equals` method in `Permission` class is implemented(using `lombok`) causes infinite recursion.

it is part of the generated code for `equals` method in  `Permission`

```
    Object this$categoryOfPermission = this.getCategoryOfPermission();
    Object other$categoryOfPermission = other.getCategoryOfPermission();
    if (this$categoryOfPermission == null) {
      if (other$categoryOfPermission != null) {
        return false;
      }
    } else if (!this$categoryOfPermission.equals(other$categoryOfPermission)) {
      return false;
    }
```

and it is the generated code for the `CategoryOfPermission` class

```
public boolean equals(final Object o) {
    if (o == this) {
      return true;
    } else if (!(o instanceof CategoryOfPermission)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      CategoryOfPermission other = (CategoryOfPermission)o;
      if (!other.canEqual(this)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        Object this$id = this.getId();
        Object other$id = other.getId();
        if (this$id == null) {
          if (other$id != null) {
            return false;
          }
        } else if (!this$id.equals(other$id)) {
          return false;
        }

        Object this$permission = this.getPermission();
        Object other$permission = other.getPermission();
        if (this$permission == null) {
          if (other$permission != null) {
            return false;
          }
        } else if (!this$permission.equals(other$permission)) {
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

as you see `Permission` class calls `equals` method of `CategoryOfPermission` class and `CategoryOfPermission` calls `equals` method of `Permision` class which finally causes stackoverflow problem!.

Comment: Thanks!!! How do you have access to the code that Lombok generates? I've search about it and it seems that I have to use Delombok. Is that right? I use Eclipse.

Comment: you are welcome, I just examined the generated code in `target` folder. Intellij automatically recreate the source code from .class file

Comment: great! Sorry if I'm asking too much, but what do you think is the best option, to use List instead Set or to override the equals method?

Comment: sorry! I really don't know the pros and cons of each approach, maybe you should ask another question. community probably better helps you

Comment: ok, thanks a lot